# SVG file format is not displayed in browser

Tags: html, svg

```html
<img src="/_layouts/test/images/Home.svg" alt="Home icon" type="image/svg+xml">
```

SVG file format is not diplayed in browser. In browser console message is displayed as 404 file not found. But files are available in exact path.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k770h4rz/ You don't need to specify the type

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="/_layouts/test/images/Home.svg" alt="Home icon" />
```